# Windows Service not starting on different computer c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows service and on start up all it does it create a new thread.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EquipmentSharingThread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc);
        EquipmentSharingThread.Name = "My Worker Thread";
        EquipmentSharingThread.IsBackground = true;
        EquipmentSharingThread.Start();
    }
```

I have been able to succesfully install this Service with Sc create on my computer which has visual studios.

However, I tried installing this service on a different computer that does not contain Visual studios and it won't even start. It keeps giving me the following error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I don't know what I could do to fix this.. any ideas?

the computers are configured in the same way.

Comment: Did you look in the event log?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: How do I look into the event log? and Windows 7

Comment: I found this : .NET Runtime version : 4.0.30319.34209 - This application could not be started.This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
 .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1

Comment: You've compiled it using v4.6 but the machine only has version 4 installed. Either compile it to v4 or install v4.6 on the target machine

Comment: Okay perfect, I am installing the new one right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to simply install the .NETFramework Version v4.6.1